# How to export CSV File wih OpenCSV Library in Android Q API 30? - Kotlin

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, opencsv

I have learn how to export CSV file in this [link](https://chetangupta.net/db-to-csv/), but I have problem to export in android API 30+. I have tried with MediaStore to writing file but no luck.

**Problem in ExportService.kt**

```
object ExportService {

    fun <T : Exportable> export(context: Context, type: Exports, content: List<T>): Flow<Boolean> =
        when (type) {
            is Exports.CSV -> writeToCSV<T>(context, type.csvConfig, content)
        }

    private fun <T : Exportable> writeToCSV(
        context: Context,
        csvConfig: CsvConfig,
        content: List<T>
    ) =
        flow {
            with(csvConfig) {
                val collection = sdk29AndUp {
                    MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
                } ?: MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
                val values = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/csv")
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        put(
                            MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/Medisy's Clinic/"
                        )
                    }
                }
                val uri = context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)
                Log.e("TAG", "writeToCSV: ${uri!!.path} $filename")
                val csvWriter = CSVWriter(FileWriter(uri!!.path?.let { File(it) }))

                StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<T>(csvWriter)
                    .withSeparator(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
                    .build()
                    .write(content)

                csvWriter.close()
            }
            emit(true)
        }
}
```

**Output Log**

```
E/TAG: writeToCSV: /external_primary/file/40 Medisy's Clinics-May_31_2022_10:58:58_AM.csv
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_primary/file/40: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
W/System.err:     at com.example.medisyclinics.data.csv.ExportService$writeToCSV$1.invokeSuspend(ExportService.kt:47)
```

Can anyone give me solutions?

Comment: Yest that path is wrong. You cannot use the path part of an uri for the File class. You know how to create a csv file. On 30+ you can use the same code. Only use a different path. No need for the media store .

Comment: Ok. thank you I will tried it in different way to get path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with Enviroment.getExternalStorageDiretory() function